# Segoe Script - Font Recommendation

Tags: fonts, typography, font-recommendation

Please I need help selecting fonts that match the **Segoe Script** family.  I am currently developing a website and I am using this font in my logo. 
 
 I am not sure what other fonts match ( Preferably Free ) .

I need it for the Headers and text content.  The site's theme is 'Fun', 'holidays', 'Travel' ect..

Assuming my logo looks like this :

[image]

## Header 1

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.

### Header 2

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. .....

Any ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: This font can be used, http://www.dafont.com/typo-comics.font

Answer (score 1):

you want to know a system default font then better you go with "monotype corsiva". What i am suggesting is to take a normal sans font, because writing style fonts are good in Logo, but if it comes to your entire website content it will not look good.